# Julia - Check if every character in string is lowercase or space

Tags: string, julia, lowercase

How do I check if every character in a string is lowercase or space?

```
"this is all lowercase"   -> true 
"THIS is Some uppercase " -> false 
"HelloWorld  "             -> false 
"hello world"              -> true
```

Comment: Clear example code for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the predicate/itr method of `all` ([docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.all-Tuple%7BAny,Any%7D):

```
julia> f(s) = all(c->islower(c) | isspace(c), s);

julia> f("lower and space")
true

julia> f("mixED")
false
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, islower hasn't existed for years. The new version is islowercase, but it works differently. islowercase can only take one character as an argument, not a full string. Here's a link to islowercase documentation:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.Unicode.islowercase

Answer (score 4):

You could also use regexes. The regex `^[a-z\s]+$` checks if you only have lowercase letters or spaces from start to end in your string.

```
julia> f(s)=ismatch(r"^[a-z\s]+$",s)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f("hello world!")
false

julia> f("hello world")
true

julia> f("Hello World")
false
```

Comment: Nice example of a regex for those of us who tend to forget regex syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't the comma inside your regex also match commas? Should it be r"^[a-z\s]+$"?

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks for spotting that typo!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by DSM, specifically the islower function, is deprecated (perhaps since 2017).  islower has been replaced by islowercase.  So, DSM's solution could be updated to:

```
julia> f(s) = all(c->islowercase(c) | isspace(c), s);

julia> f("lower and space")
true

julia> f("mixED")
false
```

If you like comprehensions, you can use those as well:

```
julia> g(s) = all([islowercase(letter) | isspace(letter) for letter in s])

julia> g("lower and space")
true

julia> g("mixED")
false
```